# bounding Heritrix depth

Tags: web-crawler

I am new to Heritrix and using heritirx 1.14.
I dont know how to do the following:
        1) bound the BFS depth of downloaded links to a specific number, for example to 3.
        2) restrict the downloaded types to html and text.

I highly appreciate your attention.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I may be confusing concepts from Heritrix 2 (which I use more) with Heritrix 1 (which I haven't used for quite a while). Sorry if I do.

The depth is a scope setting on the frontier. BroadScope would have a depth limiting setting. Or you can have scope with a DecidingScope.

As for what file types to download, I believe that should be set on the MirrorWriterProcessor you try to use to archive the crawled files (it is a sequence of DecideRules in 2.x).

By the way, wget / httrack are more easy to configure for this type of task, at least if you just need to have the most current copy of the webpage(s) in question.

Comment: thanks a lot Radtoo, but I could not find the option for the Depth in settings tab.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) bound the BFS depth of downloaded links to a specific number, for example to 3.

Set the `max-link-hops` to 3. See *6.3.2. Scope settings* from the [manual](http://www.crawler.archive.org/articles/user_manual/).

> 2) restrict the downloaded types to html and text.

Configure this in a ContentTypeRegExpFilter to only match `text/plain` and `text/html`. See *section 6.2.2.2. Provided filters* from the [manual](http://www.crawler.archive.org/articles/user_manual/).